# Relationship between mongoose and GraphQL schemas in Apollo server

Tags: mongoose, graphql, apollo-server-koa

I have this db_schema in Mongoose:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
    uid: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    dept: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Dept',
        required: true,
    },
});

const deptSchema = new Schema({
    did: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
});

const User = model('User', userSchema);
const Dept = model('Dept', deptSchema);

export { User, Dept };
```

and in GraphQL I have this schema:

```
type User {
  uid: String!
  name: String!
  dept: Dept!
}

type Dept {
  did: String!
  name: String!
}

input DeptInput {
  did: String!,
  name: String!
}


type Mutation {
  createUser(uid: String!, name: String!, dept: DeptInput): User     
}
```

in the resolver, I do:

```
Mutation: {
  createUser: async(_, { uid, name, dept }) => {
    try {

      // Create the new user
      const newUser = new User({ uid, name, dept: { did: dept.did, name: dept.name } });
      await newUser.save();

      return newUser;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Failed to create user');
    }
  }
}
```

when I try this in the playground:

```
mutation {
  createUser(uid: "5", name: "osama alatraqchi", dept: {did: "1", name: "CS"}) {
    name uid dept {did name}
  }
}
```

I get this error :

```
 "Failed to create user: Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"1\"
 (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"Dept\""
```

Note: everything is working correctly, just the problem with `createUser()`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just on the mongoose side, you've got `type` defined as an `ObjectId` in your `userSchema`

```
dept: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, <<<
        ref: 'Dept',
        required: true,
    },
});
```

But then you're passing in a `string` to your mutation: `dept: {did: "1"…`

Note also that it can be bad practice for new IDs to be mutation parameters that are passed from the front end - best to let MongoDB create IDs for you. Also best to use `ObjectIds` instead of strings as primary IDs.

Comment: then, what should i do?

Comment: its ObjectId, but reference to Dept, it must be  a correct

Comment: "1" is not an `ObjectID`